# Embedded functions for SUM and MATCH in EXCEL

Tags: excel, sum, match

So I have been trying to take the sum of a range from a different worksheet onto the current worksheet.

Currently I have 
SUM('Workers compensation'!BY(Match(B3,'Workers compensation'!BX:BX)):'Workers compensation'!BY(Match(B3,'Workers compensation'!BX:BX)))

I get #NAME? as a result. However once I press F9 on the Match functions, it works perfectly. Basically what I am wondering.... is there any way of performing the Match functions first? I want to keep it concise without having to split this into two parts so just a one lined code would be ideal. I was playing around with INDIRECT, but I am not sure this works. So basically I just need to perform the Match first because something in the function is messing up. I believe it is 'Workers compensation'!BY because once I F9 that... I get a name error.

Thanks for the help! Let me know if I was not clear in my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to refer to cell BY15 using an equation like BY(5+10) and excel just wasn't built to recognize that weird form of reference.  It won't just do math inside of a reference like that.  It'll think you're trying to use a function called "BY" with a value of 15, but there isn't a functioned named BY, which is why you're getting a NAME? error.

What you need is the index() function so that you can return a specific reference within the BY column to use in your : range.  For example you could write

```
SUM(INDEX(BY:BY,15):INDEX(BY:BY,21))
```

So what your full equation would then look like is:

```
SUM(INDEX('Workers compensation'!BY:BY,Match(B3,'Workers compensation'!BX:BX)):INDEX('Workers compensation'!BY:BY,Match(B3,'Workers compensation'!BX:BX)))
```

Comment: Since both cells are pointing to the same location, couldn't you just use `=VLOOKUP(B3,'Workers compensation'!BX:BY,2)`

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes, instead of doing an INDEX(MATCH()), you could use a VLOOKUP.  I wasn't just using match to copy the OP, I actually always use INDEX(MATCH()) because it is computationally faster and lets you do everything you can do with a VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, and some stuff you can't.  I also find it easier to troubleshoot because you can just hit F9 on the MATCH() part to see where it is looking.